What is the purpose of data-svelte-h in Svelte SSR?
I am new to Svelte and have noticed that some elements in the SSR code generated by Svelte include a special data-svelte-h attribute on them, mostly static elements but I can't seem to find a pattern.
What is the purpose of this attribute and how exactly does it help in hydration?
For example, how does it work internally, for e.g. does it compute the hash of the internal contents of the element on the server and then have that hash as its value in the rendered HTML code and then checked again on the client side?

I mean elements that don't have any interactivity attached to them, and just mere content inside them. Static content..

From the changelog:

Improve hydration speed by adding data-svelte-h attribute to detect unchanged HTML elements (#7426)

More details from the PR:


We have optimsiation to use innerHTML to create static element nodes, however, this is de-optimised, when the hydratable flag is on.
This PR allows the element nodes to be claimed using innerHTML. It will create a data-svelte hash on the element that can be optimised this way, and if the data-svelte hash does not match, it will fallback to use innerHTML to "fix" the elements.
when {@html xxx} is the only child of an element, we "optimised" by setting parent.innerHTML = xxx on mount, for both CSR and hydration. However, for hydration, this will destroy and recreate existing elements from the SSR.
When we have {@html xxx} as the only child of an element, we add data-svelte hash and only do .innerHTML if the hash does not match.


(data-svelte was renamed to data-svelte-h)
So in short: For static elements, entire sub-trees are replaced directly via innerHTML on hash mismatch rather than recursively repairing every node. If it matches, nothing has to be done for hydration.
The hash is computed during component compilation, so it should always match unless something changed the tree or a different version of the component was used between server and client.
It generates code like this for hydration:
if (get_svelte_dataset(div) !== "svelte-107ldif")
  div.innerHTML = textContent;


So the hashes are computed on both, the server and the client, right?

No, the hash is generated on compilation only (added more info on that to my answer).
